# Get the value of a changing span to make appear a other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typed.js

I would like to display a element when the typed function is writing a specific word. In my jsFiddle you can see that every thing is working but my text that I will want to show up, do not show up when it should...

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v45rkhax/1/)

Using the google chrome developer tool, I figure that my typed function is changing the span value with the text but do not set it so that my showUp function can get it...

There's a picture to help understand my point: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfGZd.png)

The goal will be to make the `h4` text (`#appear`) appear when a specific word is writing in the span (#words) and disappear when my function change the word.

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v45rkhax/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the below callback.

```
  preStringTyped: function (index) {
     $("#appear").css("display", (index == 1)?"block":"none");
  }
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/76cyh6v6/

Comment: Thanks so much for the help !! It work with my real project